# Arraylists and conditionals

Tags: java, arraylist, conditional-statements

I have an `Arraylist` which I have populated with strings.

```
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
```

Below is an example of one of the strings.

`http://asite.com/some-stuff-qua-sta/api/xml`

I have then created an `Iterator`to loop through them. This issue is I have items in the array I don't want. an example of this would be:

`http://asite.com/some-stuff-test-sta/api/xml`

Because it contains "test" I want to exclude this from the Arraylist so I added a line like this.

```
urls.remove();
```

This doesn't work so I tried to add something like this when populating the `Arraylist`.

```
!e.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent().contains("test");
```

This also doesn't work. Can someone suggest a good method to do this?

Comment: you'll need to show some more code

Comment: Iterators and for-each loops dislike it when you remove elements while they're trying to traverse the data structure.  I'd recommend a for loop going backwards, from the end of the ArrayList to the start, and removing them based on index if they contain "test"

Comment: You need an iterator to remove items from the list while you're iterating it.

Comment: @phflack They're totally fine with it if you use the `iterator.remove()` method, and if the iterator supports that method (which the iterators for mutable data structures like ArrayList generally do).

Comment: What part of the example strings are you trying to retrieve or keep from the original string? All I get from your post is that you dont want any strings that contain `test`.

Comment: @phflack No. Iterators can remove the elements while you're iterating the list.

Comment: @yshavit That's a big IF there, IF they're using `iterator.remove()`, but for all we know they could be using some form of `ArrayList.remove()`

Comment: @phflack What IF? You said: *"Iterators [...] dislike it when you remove elements while they're trying to traverse the data"*. That is simply WRONG.

Comment: @yshavit You're right. I was using an `Arraylist.remove`

Thanks all

Comment: @m0skit0 Iterators throw a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` if the iterator is not providing the changes.  Please ask me in chat if you want test cases/more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, the [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method was added to `Collection`. You can pass a `Predicate` that tests if a `String` contains `"test"` to remove those elements.

```
urls.removeIf(string -> string.contains("test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Iterator` to iterate and remove elements from the list. Since I'm not clear on what is the condition to remove, here's an example:

```
    final List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    someList.add("One");
    someList.add("Two");
    someList.add("Three");
    someList.add("Four");
    final Iterator<String> iterator = someList.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        final String curString = iterator.next();
        if (curString.startsWith("T")) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(someList);
```

Comment: The condition was "contains `test`".

Comment: @Makoto Thank you, but I think OP can modify this example to suit his needs. I'm always reluctant to provide copy-paste solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove elements from the `Iterator`, not directly from the `List` otherwyse you will have a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: **if the list is structurally modified** at any
>   time after the iterator is created, **in any way except through the
>   Iterator's own remove or add methods**, **the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException**.